# How to use XSLT to transform nodes in C# like in JS?

Tags: c#, xml, excel, xslt

[This parameterized XSLT](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/780861/XSLT-to-transform-Excel-XML-worksheet-to-named-nod) transforms the XLSX XML format into a row-by-row XML, that looks so neat it appears to be hand made:

**Input:**

```
<Row>
 <Cell>
   <Data ss:Type="String">123-44-5678</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">John</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">Doe</Data>
  </Cell>
  ...
</Row>
```

**Output:**

```
<row number="1">
        <SSN>123-44-5678</SSN>
        <First_Name>John</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Doe</Last_Name>
        ...
</row>
```

It is written in JS, but is this possible in C#?

Comment: Well, if it is just straight XSL processing, I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the *source* XML and the XSLT *stylesheet*:

```
string xmlFileName = "Book.xml";
string xslFileName = "Excel2NamedXML.xsl";
```

You can use something like this:

```
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform ();

// Optional parameter list - from the article you linked
XsltArgumentList parameters = new XsltArgumentList ();
parameters.AddParam ("nSkipRows", "", "1"); 
parameters.AddParam ("nWorksheet", "", "1"); // and so one (these will copy values to top-level correspondent `<xsl:param>` elements in the stylesheet, if they exist)

transform.Load (xslFileName);

StringWriter s = new StringWriter ();
transform.Transform (xmlFileName, parameters, s); // this line does the transformation
Console.WriteLine ("Result: " + s.ToString ()); // here just printing out the result
```